# No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://repcode;DatabaseName=reporting

Tags: java, sql-server

I have Eclipse Kepler and added sqljdbc4.jar to the classpath using properties on the project and then 'Java Build Path" and finally added under Libraries.

When I tries running the code (Run on server) i get the error:

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://repcode;DatabaseName=reporting
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)

The code:

```
package com.example.viewreport;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import java.sql.*;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Theme("viewreport")
public class ViewreportUI extends UI {

..........  CUT ..................  

    String userName = "report";
    String password = "report";

    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://repcode;DatabaseName=reporting"; 

    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
    } catch (SQLException e) {              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Some vaadin code is stripped out from the above source.

What am I missing?
The SQL server is a 2008 R2

The code is run on a local tomcat catalina instance

Answer (score 1):

Try This

Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost/DatabaseName","userName","password");

Comment: Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance(); does not work with sqljdbc4.jar. That is taken care of in Driver.Manager.getConnection

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line before creating a connection.  `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");`

Comment: That is not neccesary for sqljdbc4.jar and just creates an error

Comment: What is the error? according to microsoft own example loading the driver class is necessary. link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa342339.aspx

Comment: Check under making a simple Connection http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378526.aspx